# Transforming all array values into hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, iteration

Beginner question here, sorry:

I have an array named data. It consists of an array of hashes I .mapped out of a CSV:

```
[
{:status=>"new", :number=>"215", :subject=>"25", :case=>"First", :attachment=>"alpha, beta"},
{:status=>"old", :number=>"213", :subject=>"21", :case=>"Second", :attachment=>"alpha, beta"}
]
```

I want to post the hashes to an API, but this API expects all values to be arrays (because they can all potentially hold multiple values).
How do I transform the values for all hashes into arrays?
Expected result, like so:

```
[
{:status=>["new"], :number=>["215"], :subject=>["25"], :case=>["First"], :attachment=>["alpha", "beta"]}
{:status=>["old"], :number=>["213"], :subject=>["21"], :case=>["Second"], :attachment=>["alpha", "beta"]}
]
```

I know I can do:

```
hashed_data[0].map { |k, v| [ k,[v] ] }.to_h
```

But how do I apply that to each hash in the array?

In this case I can't directly call :attachment because it won't always be named the same way.

Comment: Your hashes have the status key two times, they aren't valid hashes. Is that your real case?

Comment: @SebastianPalma, strictly saying, they are valid (at least in Ruby 2.4.1)

Comment: Depending on what's valid, but if you apply any operation to that first hash, expecting the result contains also duplicated keys, then the result won't be the expected. The result will contain the last definition of the repeated key -
 as in previous Ruby versions.

Comment: @SebastianPalma ah crap. my mistake - it's a different key in reality, typed it double. Changed it to prevent confusion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mutate existing array, I would do something like:

```
array.each {|e| e.transform_values! {|value| Array(value)} }
#=> [{:status=>["25"], :number=>["215"], :case=>["First"], :attachment=>["alpha, beta"]}, 
#    {:status=>["21"], :number=>["213"], :case=>["Second"], :attachment=>["alpha, beta"]}]
```

Comment: this does not produce the desired value for `attachment` which is an `Array` of `["alpha","beta"]` as individual elements rather than a single `String`

Comment: @engineersmnky, true, I left is as a homework, SO is not a *did-my-work-instead-of-me* site :)

Comment: @Ilya thanks! That would solve 90% of my cases. I intentionally didn't ask fr a sollution for the attachments as I'm interested in finding that one out for myself :))